# Dense INPUT Layer: When do I have to specify the input shape?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

In the below code:

1. I get an error when I do not specify the input shape in the $1^{st}$ layer. I thought that TensorFlow can infer the shape for the dense layer. For some code I have seen, TensorFlow works without the input shape specified.
2. What is the input shape I should specify? X is (9, ). By default, am I supposed to omit the sample size for the input shape?

````
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

import pandas as pd


from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, SimpleRNN, GRU, LSTM, Conv1D, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed

X = [1, 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9,  10]
Y = [10, 15,20, 25, 30, 35, 45, 50, 55]
  
sample_size=len(X)
X = np.array(X).reshape(9, )
Y = np.array(Y).reshape(9, )
print(X.shape)
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Dense(100,input_shape=[1]))
model.add(Dense(100))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500,  batch_size=sample_size, verbose=1)

```
````

Comment: The first layer in every `Sequential` model requires an `input_shape` argument, so that it can infer the shapes of the trainable parameters like weights and biases.

Answer (score 0):

1. My `TensorFlow 2.6` can infer the `input_shape` in `.fit()`.
2. Yes, omit the sample size, (1, ) is your `input_shape`.

P.S. if you do not specify your `input_shape`, you cannot call `.summary()` before `.fit()`